# Cómo esperar a que se realice un seteo de un hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Necesito realizar el seteo de setPath y unas vez que ya se haya seteado, realizar el de setOpen (el cual abre un slide), actualmente abre el slide pero el valor de Path se muestra hasta que lo cierro. Es decir, necesito asegurarme que el setPath finalice para poder setear setOpen.

````
        let listRef = storageRef.child('root/'+carpeta);
        let aux = []; 
        // Find all the prefixes
        listRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
                res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
                    aux.push((folderRef._delegate._location.path_).split('/')[2]);
                });
            }).catch(function(error) {
        });
        setShortPath(aux);
        setDepto(dp);
        setOpenSlide(!openSlide);
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Sabiendo que los hooks son asíncronos puedes crear una función asíncrona e instanciar en el catch

```
const hazAlgo = async () = {
        await setShortPath(aux);
        await setDepto(dp);
        await setOpenSlide(!openSlide);
}
```

Dentro de tu catch

```
let listRef = storageRef.child('root/'+carpeta);
let aux = []; 
// Find all the prefixes
listRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
        res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
            aux.push((folderRef._delegate._location.path_).split('/')[2]);
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
});
hazAlgo();
```

} ```